# extracting url of an anchor with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm looping through cells of a table and the structure of each cell goes like this:

```
<td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack..." class="MyLink">1</a></td>
```

I'm writing this to extract the href's value but it's not working.

```
$('.MyLink').each(function () {
    test = $(this).attr();
    alert(test);
});
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.MyLink').each(function () {
    test = $(this).attr("href");
    alert(test);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not getting any attribute - you need to pass 'href' into the `attr` function:

```
$('.MyLink').each(function () {
    test = $(this).attr('href');
    alert(test);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
.attr('href');
```

That said, be careful about how you use the value.  To turn it into something you can actually execute in your `.click()` handler (per your other question) requires the `eval` function which can have nasty security issues.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define which attribute you want

e.g. `test = $(this).attr('href');`